# IIFE jquery ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-namespaces, iife

I am working on a web project that has a large amount of javascript and we started hitting namespace collisions because we were adding everything to "$.".

I read up about namespacing and found the great article at http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/

I tried to set up the namespace inside of an IIFE as recommended and thought I was in luck because the function was already setup as

```
(function() { ... });
```

so I converted it to:

```
(function(namespace, undefined) { ... })(window.stuff = window.stuff || {});
```

only to find (after hours of work) that actually the original was

```
$(function() { ... }
```

Which means it was all being called in jQuery's ready() function.

I would like to keep the namespacing IIFE but cannot figure out how I would use it within jQuery's ready() function. Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var namespace = (function() {
    // local variables and functions

    function readyHandler($) {
         // DOM ready code
         $("selector").method();
    }

    // exposed methods
    return {
        readyHandler: readyHandler
    };
})();

jQuery(namespace.readyHandler);
```

Comment: After some careful partitioning of the existing code I was able to bascially do what this answer suggests: Create your namespace and expose API methods to call from jQuery's ready() function.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, not sure if you got the concepts straight... None of those functions looks like an **Immediately Invoked Function Expression** because you're not invoking the function.

```
(function() { ... } ());
                  --^-- invoke function
```

jQuery's `ready` already creates a new closure so you don't need an IIFE anyway.

In any case, when using jQuery you can namespace your plugin in the `$` namespace with an object that way you don't pollute it.

```
$.myplugin = {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did mean what you wrote but missed the ending (). I have modified my question.

Also, I am not creating a jquery plugin but rather my own code which should be namespaced separately. The problem is that the code I am inheriting simply added everything to the jQuery ($) namespace even though it should have been in its own.